# How is missing values handled in a stepwise model process?

Tags: r, missing-data, stepwise-regression

Suppose I have 100 observations among 4 variables, a Y with no missing values, then X1, X2, X3 that each have 10 (distinct) missing values, so that the complete case analysis has only N=70 observations.

When performing forward stepwise model selection, the variable selection sequence may be determined by fitting models (using R formula notation)

```
Y ~ 1
Y ~ X1
Y ~ X2 
Y ~ X3
Y ~ X1 + X2
...
```

In each case, what is the sample size for each model under consideration? Would it be N=100, N=90, N=90, N=90,  N=80, ... corresponding to the above models? Or would it be N=70 even if the final model `Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3` would never be reached in the forward stepwise process?

Comment: Nothing wrong with this question (+1) but I would opt for causally-informed Bayesian imputation.

Answer (score 1):

This is yet another problem with automated methods.

If you do this by hand, you have your choice, but not are good and you'd sort of have to pick one in advance. Delete everything and you lower power. But doing the regressions on different data sets really causes problems, especially if the missingness is not MCAR or MAR.

If you do it using stepAIC in R, then there is a note:

> The model fitting must apply the models to the same dataset. This may
> be a problem if there are missing values and an na.action other than
> na.fail is used (as is the default in R). We suggest you remove the
> missing values first.

But this is just one of the problems with stepwise. The others have been discussed here many times.